# Intuition for Algebraic Value of Covariant Derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, surfaces

Reading through Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces,* the following statement is made on an algebraic value for the covariant derivative (pg. 252, section 4-4):

> **Proposition 3:** Let $x(u,v)$ be an orthogonal parametrization (that is, $F = 0$), of a neighborhood
> of an oriented surface $S$, and $w(t)$ be a differentiable field of unit vectors along the curve
> $x(u(t), v(t))$. Then,
> $$[\frac{Dw}{dt}] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\{G_{u}\frac{dv}{dt} - E_{v}\frac{du}{dt}\} + \frac{d \varphi}{dt},$$
> where $\varphi(t)$ is the angle from $x_{u}$ to $w(t)$ in the given orientation

The proof of this statement is given in the text. My question is: *what does this mean?* My linear algebra is a bit rusty, so I'm not sure if that's the intuition I'm missing, but is there any extra intuition, geometric or otherwise, to be taken away from this expression of the covariant derivative (regarding the fundamental form and what it means for the surface), or is it just a tidy way of expressing the derivative that will make computation for other proofs more manageable? It certainly achieves the latter part, but I feel like I'm missing some important details on the former, more intuitive part.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen a geometric picture of what the covariant derivative represents? For what it's worth, you can think of the covariant derivative as generalising the directional derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to other spaces. This algebraic expression is just something that allows us to make concrete computations.

Comment: For me personally, I found it much easier to swallow when I looked at the general construction of the covariant derivative, which involves the Christoffel symbols. The expression do Carmo gives is really just a computation of the Christoffel symbols in small dimensions.

Comment: @mizh Figure 4-8 in the same chapter is an illustration of the covariant derivative, I'm not sure if there are illustrations that shine more light on the matter. I understand that it's a (normal) projection of the derivative of the vector field restricted to some appropriate curve onto the tangent plane. I think I get what's going on as far as that goes, I'm just not sure if there's any additional useful information to be understood from this specific algebraic expression. If it's just a useful expression we can use to do some concrete calculations, I can be happy with that.

Comment: @mizh I haven't gotten too much into the Christoffel symbols much more than acknowledging their existence in the construction. I'll definitely have to do that. Do you consider it paramount to grasp what's being said about parallel transport in this section?

Comment: I would definitely say parallel transport is something that intuitively makes sense, computationally is hard to do the first time, but definitely worthwhile. For what it's worth, I'm also more algebraically minded, so when I see the general construction with Christoffel symbols, then the values obtained for $n=3$ just 'make sense' to me. Ted's text is a very helpful source in general, and I think his answer might be more of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about the intuition in my (free) differential geometry text (linked in my profile).  It's a superposition principle: The first term is telling you at what rate the frame $\{x_u/\sqrt E,x_v/\sqrt G\}$ is rotating, and you add to that $d\phi/dt$, which tells you at what rate your unit-length vector field $w$ is rotating relative to the frame.